# Cartesian product of two Dataframes and Sum of the cartesion result in Spark(scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have two DataFrame's(Spark scala) like Below :

```
df1 is Array((1,WrappedArray(1,2,3)),(2,WrappedArray(1,2,4)))
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, features: array<float>]

df2 is Array((1,WrappedArray(4,5,6)),(2,WrappedArray(3,5,6)))
```

first i have to produce Cartesian and summation of the array values of above two df's.

for example Cartesian is like below:

```
((11,(Array(1,2,3),Array(4,5,6))),(12,(Array(1,2,3),Array(3,5,6))),(21,(Array(1,2,4),Array(4,5,6))),(22,(Array(1,2,4),Array(3,5,6))))
```

Cartesian and summation like below:

Array((11,1*4+2*5+3*6) ,(12,1*3+2*5+3*6),(21,(1*4+2*5+4*6))(22,(1*3+2*5+4*6))

I have tried Cartesian like below :

```
scala> val cart=df1.cartesian(df2)
```

but i am getting error

```
<console>:41: error: value cartesian is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

after that i have converted  df to rdd using RDD.i.e df.rdd
after that i have tried `ufrdd.cartesian(miftrdd).map{
case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (((k1.toString).zip(k2.toString))) -> v1.zip(v2).map(x => x._1 * x._2).reduce(_ + _)
}.foreach(println)` 
but i am getting error like

```
 error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

please help me on this how to achieve

Array((11,1*4+2*5+3*6) ,(12,1*3+2*5+3*6),(21,(1*4+2*5+4*6))(22,(1*3+2*5+4*6))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you convert from dataframe to rdd so rdd has type `RDD[Row]` not `RDD[(Int, List[Int])]`.
You can convert dataframe to dataset by `as[(Int, List[Int])]`, then transform dataset to rdd by `.rdd`, you will get `RDD[(Int, List[Int])]`.

I think rest of the code will work completely fine.